# jquery: on each click event append and increment input name

Tags: jquery

Each time the button is clicked I need this to increment the name='0fName' by one so the php script sees a unique name and does not overwrite the previous item.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addMember').click(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++); 
        console.log("addMember was called");
        $("#addfamMember").append("<input type='text' name='0fName'>");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Future note: that is invalid markup for `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

Add a counter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count=0;
    $('#addMember').click(function() {
        console.log("addMember was called");
        $("#addfamMember").append("<input type='text' name='" + count + "fName'>");
        count++;
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach could be changing a name attribute to `fName[]`:

```
$('#addMember').click(function () {
    $("#addfamMember").append("<input type='text' name='fName[]'>");
    return false;
});
```

In this case data will be sent as `fName` array which may be more convenient to deal with than with a bunch of separate parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Like epascarello says, add a counter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var counter = 0;

$('#addMember').click(function() {
    console.log("addMember was called");
    $("#addfamMember").append("<input type='text' name='" + counter + "fName'>");

    counter++;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You need to fix `name=counter + 'fName'` then it'll be correct

Answer (score 1):

`.index()` will do this too:

```
$('#addMember').click(function() {
    var idx = $(':input:last').index();
    $("#addfamMember").append("<input type='text' name='" + idx + "fName'>");
    return false;
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tTQL9/)